# How to insert table row if and only if first cell value of a row is not equals to first cell value of next row?

Tags: jquery

```
             <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>aaa</td>
                   <td>111</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>aaa</td>
                   <td>222</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>bbb</td>
                   <td>111</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td>bbb</td>
                   <td>222</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
```

In this example second row first cell value 'aaa' and third row first cell value 'bbb' are not same. Now How to add a new table row between second row and third row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to create elements from markup, and [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to add them before a specific element:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var $prev = $(this).prev("tr");
    if ($prev.length
        && $("td:first", $prev).text() != $("td:first", this).text()) {
        $("<tr><td>New</td><td>Row</td></tr>").insertBefore(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Change insertAfter to insertBefore and I'll +1:)

Comment: New row coming between third row and forth row, after forth row. But third row first cell value and forth row first cell value is same.

Comment: Hello PaulPRO, insertBefore replaced new row between all current rows. It is not satisfied my task.

Comment: @Paul, you're absolutely right, I was adding the new row in the wrong direction. Answer fixed, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Just you just send me a notification with @Paul when my username is Paulpro? It worked and I got the notification. Cool haha. And +1 on your answer :)